# Files Download from UITableView Cell - mixing up

Tags: uitableview, nsurlconnection

Download button are placed on all cell in UITableView. When I click once at a time and wait until it finish downloading, the file that I received are fine, but when I click 2 or more on download button, the files that I received are all mixing up. Please could some one help me.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];
    NSInteger bytes = [data length] + [[dict objectForKey:@"receivedBytes"] intValue];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:bytes] forKey:@"receivedBytes"];


    int row = [[dict objectForKey:@"row"] intValue];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [self.aTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    [myWebData appendData:data];
    [dict setObject:myWebData forKey:@"myData"];
}

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
 //Write file to folder
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [self getConnectionInfo:connection];

    [self.activeConnections removeObject:dict];
    NSString *fileName = [dict valueForKey:@"fName"];;
    DLOAD_PATH = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",DLOAD_PATH0,fileName];

    NSData *myData1 = [dict objectForKey:@"myData"];
    [myData1 writeToFile:DLOAD_PATH atomically:YES];}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. Just add to dictionary:

NSMutableData *myWebData1 = (NSMutableData *)[dict objectForKey:@"myMutData"];

[myWebData1 appendData:data];

Answer (score 0):

use this for download more then one image

[HCDownload](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hcdownload)

for detail see my answer at [Downloading images from server and saving into Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621944/downloading-images-from-server-and-saving-into-database/16622815#16622815)

Comment: Note: The files that I try to download are *.mp3 and not image.